# Correctly applying Disjunctive Syllogism

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

If one has $\neg p \vee q$ and $\neg q$, does one need to apply the Commutative Law to $\neg p \vee q$ to obtain $q \vee \neg p$, before concluding that $\neg p$   ?

Comment: You can define the rule either way.